# Puppet on Azure to manage non-Azure nodes

Tags: azure, puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

I have installed a Puppet Server on Azure and is currently managing a number of Puppet Agents on Azure as well. I am using the internal azure fqdn - this means that all manifests and tasks processes are sent using the internal Azure network.

Now I want to use the same Puppet server to manage nodes outside Azure. However when I use the public DNS of puppet server, the agent is failing due to incorrect CA domain.

Is there a way to specify to CAs in Puppet server? One for Azure hosts, and other for non-Azure hosts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add multiple dns names to my puppetmaster?](https://serverfault.com/questions/320028/how-to-add-multiple-dns-names-to-my-puppetmaster). See the answers how to specify multiple DNS names in the Puppet Server certificate.